# Cannot read property 'template' of undefined at MatRowDef.push

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading, mat-table

I am using Angular lazy loading. When switching from one child component to another, getting an error at a component where I'm displaying a table mat-table and data is not displayed in table.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of undefined
    at MatRowDef.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.BaseRowDef.extractCellTemplate

```
           <ng-container *ngIf="listService.scheduledDdataSource">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="listService.scheduledDdataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>Date</b></th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="branch">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>Branch</b></th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <a href="//{{element.branch}}"
                            target="_blank">{{element.branch}}</a>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="version">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>Version</b></th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.version}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="user">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>User</b></th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.user}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="deployed">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>Status</b></th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deployed}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="domain">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>Domain</b></th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.domain}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        <div class="action-icons">
                            <div class="item">
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <div class="material-icons">
                            <button mat-button appModalDirective (click)="listService.selectRow(element)"
                                [modalId]="'cancel'">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/baseline-cancel-24px.svg">
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </th>
                </ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="listService.displayedColumnsSch"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: listService.displayedColumnsSch;">
</tr>
</table>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem is that you don't call your data correctly so the container is unable to read it. it seems like you are addressing your service directly instead of creating a method in your component that `subscribes` to it

Here is an example of my data table that works :

Component :

```
dataSource : any = new MatTableDataSource;

     ngOnInit() {
        this.marinService.getAllContainers().subscribe((result) => {
         //Data
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
      }}
```

This is the HTML table :

```
    <!-- Pagenaitor-->
    <mat-paginator style="font-size: 22" [pageSize]="1" [pageSizeOptions]="[1,10, 20, 30, 50, 100]">
    </mat-paginator>
  <!-- Container Table -->
  <div>
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  [hidden]="!show" matSort >
      <!-- Location  -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="AITOR">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.AITOR}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
          <!-- Type  -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="SOG_MCOLH">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > Container Type </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.SOG_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
              <!-- Height  -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="GOBH_MCOLH">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Container Height </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.GOBH_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>    
              <!-- Length  -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="AORKH_MCOLH">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Container Lenght </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.AORKH_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container> 
               <!-- Number  -->
               <ng-container matColumnDef="MCOLH_N7">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Container Number </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.MCOLH_N7}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container> 
                    <!-- Name AAAA  -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="MCOLH_AAAA">
                      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Container Name </mat-header-cell>
                      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.MCOLH_AAAA}} </mat-cell>
                      </ng-container>  
                     <!-- QTSR Hebrow  -->
                     <ng-container matColumnDef="TAOR_QTSR_EBRI">
                     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Storage Site </mat-header-cell>
                     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.TAOR_QTSR_EBRI}} </mat-cell>
                     </ng-container>   
                                  <!-- Storage Code  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="QOD_MCHSN">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Storage Code </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.QOD_MCHSN}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
                                 <!-- Status  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="STTOS_RASHI_4_1">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.STTOS_RASHI_4_1}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>      
                                  <!-- MQOTSR Hebrow  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="LQOCH_SHM_MQOTSR_EBRI">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Customer MQOTSR </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.LQOCH_SHM_MQOTSR_EBRI}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
                                  <!-- MQOTSR Hebrow  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ESN </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
                                  <!-- MQOTSR Hebrow  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="LQOCH_QOD_LQOCH">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Code Customer </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.LQOCH_QOD_LQOCH}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>            

    <!--Row Maker-->
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumn"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumn;" ></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
    </div>
```

This table gets the data from the services and goes of the Json it gets filling the array.

Comment: Thing is that I have 2 tables in this component both of them are using same service for data. Just 1 table fails with this error, another one works perfectly. I am setting all needed parameters for ListService in my main component ngOnInit and reaching a data retrieved from service - directly from template. If I reload a page after error, data is received in table.